# Can I sell my own PyQt4 app built with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I know PyQt4 has GPL licence. But I'm confused:

How can I sell my app built with cx_freeze?

Can I do it legally?
what should I do otherwise?

Do compiled py files also mean source code?

I don't want to change my code for PySide, which has LGPL. I want to sell PyQt4 built with cx_freeze if it is legal.

Comment: read this http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html

Comment: It doesn't say yes or no for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IANAL but here is a quick summary.

1. Yes, you can sell it even though it is GPL.
2. However, since PyQt4 is GPL, then your entire application is also GPL which means anyone who receives a copy (e.g., purchases it) is legally allowed to redistribute it for free or for money and there is nothing you can do to prevent it.
3. Unless you purchase a commercial license for PyQt4 in which case you can maintain your proprietary license so long as you also follow the licensing restrictions/rules of any third-party libraries that you also use.

Comment: There's also [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), which works like PyQt4, but is LGPL, so you can use it in a proprietary project.

Comment: But can you sell it using cx_freeze? LGPL means that you don't have to share the source code but if the program uses libraries that are LGPL, like Qt, in this case, the customer should be able to change the Qt version with its own. Do you think it's possible?